# how can i see the latest records initially when i do collection find?

Tags: mongodb

I have some huge collection of records resent in my mongodb 
This is the sample

```
db.logins.find().pretty()

        "cust_id" : "testuser",
        "error" : "no error"

        "cust_id" : "testuser",
        "error" : "unable to connect"

    "cust_id" : "sam",
        "error" : "no error"

        "cust_id" : "sdert",
        "error" : "unable to connect"
```

When i do `db.logins.find().pretty()` it displays records of the past (old ones)

I need to execute the command `it` contnously to see them

My question is , how can i see the latest records initially when i do `db.logins.find().pretty()`??

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/). That is if you have a field that contains a date object you can use it to sort the results. That is,

```
 db.logins.find().sort({date_field: -1}).pretty()
```

`-1` signifies that the records will be sorted in descending order.

If it is of any help, you can try sorting by [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order)

```
 db.logins.find().sort({$natural: -1}).pretty()
```

This however does not guarantee that sorted results will match the insertion order. Sorting on a date field will still be better.

Comment: How do you determine that a document is the latest one? There should be at least one field in your document that will provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $natural here as well, which will give mostly the same effect (not totally due to distributed environments):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/natural/

```
db.logins.find().sort({$natural:-1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the _id field that MongoDB generates for you - the first four bytes are the timestamp so sorting on it descending will give you reverse insertion order.

The difference between using _id and $natural is the latter gives them in disk order, and there may not be a guarantee that your records have been written contiguously on disk where ascending order of _id field is guaranteed.

```
db.logins.find().sort({_id:-1})
```

In addition, the _id has an index on it, sort it's used for sort to avoid the performance hit sorting would otherwise take.

Comment: "been written contiguously on disk where ascending order of _id field is guaranteed." I would not say that line, I have a fb like news feed which I still sort on a date field since the _id will actually give documents back in the wrong order at times. It really depends on how the application does things I have found

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for normally generated _id field (ObjectId) not be in ascending order. Disk order _can_ be irregular if you do any deletes on the collection, or updates, etc.

Comment: I can see one way, exactly at what time the ObjectId is made. However, yes I create the date object and _id object at the same time in my php app and the _id object does not always reflect the date object in terms of order. Might be only one item out of order but it is still one